# Unexpected output (C strings and characters)

Tags: c

I'm just starting off with characters and arrays. I wrote some code to generate a string of certain random and non-random characters. Well, actually it's supposed to generate bargain codes for Dominos pizza. Ahem...

Anyway, this is the code, and I'm perplexed by lack of any output whatsoever. I compiled with gcc -Wall, and there's no warning or errors. So it's apparent that it's some fundamental structural aspect regarding strings.

I'd appreciate any insights regarding this.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include "conio.h"
#include <time.h>


int genrandom(int,int);
char randAlph(void);
char letterize(int);
char randDigit(void);
char digitize(int);
void weaver(void);
void prtall(char[],int);


int main (void) {

    srand(time(0));  
    weaver();
    return 0; 
}



void weaver(void) {
  //BG5C?---1
    char word[10];
    word[0]='B';
    word[1]='G';
    word[2]='5';
    word[3]='C';
    word[4]=randDigit();
    word[5]=randAlph();
    word[6]=randAlph();
    word[7]=randAlph();
    word[8]='\0';
    prtall(word,8);
}

void prtall(char worder[],int len){       
    int i;
    for (i=0;(i=len);i++) {
      if ( worder[i] != '\0' ){
    printf("%c",worder[i]);
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
}   

int genrandom(int mino,int maxo) {
    int val=mino+rand()/(RAND_MAX/(maxo-mino)+1);
    return val;  
}

char randAlph (void){
  int val;
  char text;
  val=genrandom(0,26);
  text=letterize(val);
  return text;

}

char randDigit () {
    int val;
    char text;
    val=genrandom(0,9);
    text=digitize(val);
    return text;                            
}

char letterize(int num) {
  char letter='A'+num;
  return letter;
}

char digitize(int num) {
  char digit='0'+num;
  return digit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (i=0;(i=len);i++)`

**Did you mean i <= len** ?

`i=len` is an `assignment`, returns true if assignment succeeds.

So what happens is

*i gets assigned the value of len, (which is successful) hence returns true.*

Hence for loop condition gets satisfied.

What you need is

```
           for (i=0;i<=len;i++)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for (i=0;(i=len);i++)
```

should be

```
for (i=0;i<=len;i++)
```

Comment: +1 for catching that it should (in this case, from what the loop appears to want to be doing) be `<=` and not `<`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you through the trouble to 0-terminate your array, just print it with:

```
puts(word);
```

or

```
printf("%s\n", word);
```

to get the line-feed.

No need to loop yourself and print one character at a time.

Comment: Thanks for telling me the simplest way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

Your stuck in an infinite loop, the problem is with the `for` statement:

```
for (i=0;(i=len);i++) {
```

You want `i<=len`, not `i=len`. Your for loop right now is doing:

```
i = 0, i = 8
if '\0' != '\0'
i++ (i = 9)
```

Then when it goes to "check" the condition it really just resets `i` to 8